# Getting null object from Spring controller to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

Here's my Spring controller (resource class) method:

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
public class CartResources {

    @Autowired 
    CartService cartService; 

    @RequestMapping("/{cartId}") 
    public @ResponseBody 
    Cart getCartById (@PathVariable(value = "cartId") int cartId) 
    { 
        Cart cart =  cartService.getCartById(cartId);
        CartItem item = cart.getCartItems().get(0); 

        Product product = item.getProduct(); 

        System.out.println(product.getProductName()); 
        return cart; 
        }
}
```

Here's my angular js class:

```
var cartApp = angular.module ("cartApp", []);
cartApp.controller("cartCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.refreshCart = function (cartId) {
        $http.get('/eGrocery/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
           $scope.cart=data;

           //CODE BELOW IS FOR TESTING PURPOSES 
           var product = $scope.cart.cartItems[0].product; 
           var item = $scope.cart.cartItems[0]; 

           if(item == null) 
            alert("item is null"); 
           else 
               alert("total price is" + item.totalPrice); 
         if(product == null) 
             alert("product is null"); 
         else 
           alert("product name is" + product.productName); 

        });
    };

 $scope.initCartId = function (cartId) {
        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };
```

Here's the HTML file:

```
 <section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div ng-controller = "cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">       
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>                 
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat = "item in cart.cartItems">
                    <td>{{item.product.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
            </div>
```

**Brief explanation of the code:**

The Spring controller is supposed to pass a Cart object to AngularJS class. The `cart` object contains `cartItem` object, which contains a `product` object.

**The problem:**

In the AngularJS file, when I try to retrieve any attribute of the Product object, I get null. In fact, the entire `product` object is null. However, the `cartItem` object is not null. For instance, I can retrieve the value of `cartItem.totalPrice`.

The strange thing here is that in the Spring controller class, I explicitly printed out the values of the Product object and they were not null. So, I don't know why AngularJS gets a null Product. Please help.

Comment: Try adding a break-point in your success handler and inspect that state of `data`? This is likely a `response` Object  containing a bunch of properties such as data, headers, status etc. You may need to change your code to `$scope.cart = response.data`. Alternatively, check the response of the network call in your browsers Developer Tools to ensure the structure is as you expect?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I realized that I put @JsonIgnore on my Product class for some reason. Looking at the data in on the source view helped me realize. Thanks.